# css page-break-before property works only for the first table element in a page (firefox)

Tags: css, printing, page-break

I want to make nice prints of large tables, each having its own ID, putting each one on a new sheet. I applyed the css style page-break-before to each table ID in the stylesheet directly.

HTML like this :

```
<table id="T1">...</table>
<table id="T2">...</table>
```

CSS like this :

```
#div1 #div2 #T1, #div1 #div2 #T2, ... {diplay: inline; page-break-before: always;}
```

And this does not work in Chromium, in Firefox it only puts the page break on the first element and ignores the following table elements. The style is "higly selected", as top property in firebug.

I put the "display: inline;" property as I read that page-break property doesn't work with absolute positioned elements, so I had doubts with block display as well...

I really can't figure out what I did wrong....

Answer (score 0):

According to this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/page-break-before

It will only apply to block elements. So you should be using `display:block` or just leave the display value to automatic which will render as a table *(tables are block elements)*. I would be very surprised if mixing `position:absolute` with `page-break-before` will work... So I would advise you to try without the absolute positioning and see what happens.

Also is there any reason why you are being so specific with your selectors:

```
#div1 #div2 #T1, #div1 #div2 #T2, ...
```

Just to make sure there isn't an error in there probably best to just use:

```
#T1, #T2, ... {}
```

IDs after all should be unique.

On another note, the above link states about trying to use `break-before` ... you could give this a go and see if it helps?